# How to know what is the most viewed node without installing a module?

Tags: 10

How to know what is the most viewed node withotut installing a module?

Is there a core way to do that months (more than one year) after enabling the statistics module?

Comment: The statistics module provides a block *Popular content*. It also provides a Views integration. See web/core/modules/statistics/statistics.views.inc

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below code to get most viewd node by using preprocess function in your `.theme` file.get statistics count for all required nodes.

Save Node name and count in a array, then later check array for largest count.

```php
function [THEME_NAME]_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
//get all node ids
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node') ->condition('status', 1) ->condition('type', 'YOUR-NODE-TYPE') ->execute(); 
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
// now with foreach loop save each node name and count in array
foreach ($nids as $nid){
$node_name = Node::load($nid); $node_details->field_FIELD_NAME->value; 
  $statistics = statistics_get($variables['node']->id());
  $variables['node_stats'] = \Drupal::translation()->formatPlural($statistics['totalcount'], '1 view', '@count views');
}
```

Comment: In which file do you put this code and where do you print the output? BTW please review my edit.

Comment: put this code in  your .theme file using preprocess function .  you can print output node_stats inside template file like below. 


    <span class="node__stats">
      {{ node_stats }}
    </span>

This will print the node statistics count in submitted area of content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the core statistics module to get the count of views for each node or you can write simple code to get same result..

```
function getMostViewedNodeBetweenDates($start_timestamp, $end_timestamp) {
  // Query the database for the node with the highest view count.
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1) // Published nodes.
    ->condition('type', 'article'); // Change 'article' to the desired content type.

  // Add a condition for the date range.
  $query->condition('created', [$start_timestamp, $end_timestamp], 'BETWEEN');

  // Sort the nodes by view count in descending order.
  $query->sort('statistics_counter_totalcount', 'DESC');
  $query->range(0, 1); // Retrieve only one result, the most viewed node.

  // Execute the query and get the result.
  $nids = $query->execute();

  // If we have results, load the most viewed node.
  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $most_viewed_nid = reset($nids);
    $most_viewed_node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($most_viewed_nid);
    return $most_viewed_node;
  }

  // No nodes found.
  return null;
}
```

You can then call this function in your custom code to get the most viewed node:

```
$start_timestamp = strtotime('2023-01-01');
$end_timestamp = strtotime('2023-12-31');

$mostViewedNode = getMostViewedNodeBetweenDates($start_timestamp, $end_timestamp);

if ($mostViewedNode) {
  // Do something with $mostViewedNode.
  $title = $mostViewedNode->getTitle();
  $viewCount = $mostViewedNode->get('statistics_counter_totalcount')->value;
  // ...
}
else {
  // No most viewed node found in the specified date range.
}
```

I hope this answers your question.